# Sum values in column

Tags: javascript, html, symfony

I can't sum the subtotals of an HTML column table using javascript. I need to sum the 5th column and put the result in a textbox so the costumer can see the totals of his bill. The thing is, I can't use database because it is a table that doesn't INSERT the value in the database until I hit the final button. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot

```
var arr2 = "";
$('#añadir').click(function() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tablaC");
  var id_pla = document.getElementById("plato_id").value;
  var pla = document.getElementById("plato_nombre").value;
  var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
  var punitario = document.getElementById("plato_precio").value;
  var subtotal = (cantidad * punitario)

  if (id_pla != "" && cantidad != "") {
    var row = table.insertRow(cant);
    var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);

    cell0.innerHTML = cant;
    cell1.innerHTML = id_pla;
    cell2.innerHTML = pla;
    cell3.innerHTML = cantidad;
    cell4.innerHTML = punitario;
    cell5.innerHTML = subtotal;

    cant++;
    arr2 += id_pla + "," + cantidad + ","
    $('#arr').val(arr2);

  }
  validar();

});
```

This is the HTML code

```
    <table id="tablaC" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID Pedido</th>
            <th>ID Plato</th>
            <th>Plato</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Precio Unitario</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input id="arr"  name="arr" value="" />
    <br>

    <br/>

    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Crear Registro" id="registro">
</form>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Why can't you sum the total?

Comment: please post the html document to have more clarity

Comment: why dont' you iterate over the result set in your controller to get the total and pass that to the view instead of using javascript, I'd hate to think that you are using this JS calculated value and storing it in your database, it can be easily changed by a user to be whatever they want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice several issues in your files codes, you should fix them in order to make this work:

1)

To compare with "" You should use strict equality "!==" instead of "!="

```
      if (id_pla !== "" && cantidad !== "") {
```

instead of:

```
      if (id_pla != "" && cantidad != "") {
```

2)  "$" is not defined as a variable, unless you refer to jQuery.

```
    /*here*/  $('#añadir').click(function() {
```

3) Ids missing in your HTML code:

Here you are saying:

```
     var table = document.getElementById("tablaC");
     var id_pla = document.getElementById("plato_id").value;
     var pla = document.getElementById("plato_nombre").value;
     var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
     var punitario = document.getElementById("plato_precio").value;
```

But you are not giving any id to this elements on your html. It should be like this:

```
    <th>ID Pedido</th>
    <th id="plato_id">ID Plato</th>
    <th id="plato_nombre">Plato</th>
    <th id="cantidad">Cantidad</th>
    <th id="plato_precio">Precio Unitario</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
```

Comment: "$" is shortcode for jQuery - how do you know jQuery has not been included and it is not defined? The OP hasn't posted the whole html only snippets

Comment: You are right, I tough he was missing to define a variable called "$"             like: var $ = document.getElementById("arr");

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Anyways, I solved those issues in my code but the only thing left for it to fully work is the totals